# Get row number of a FindFirst result in VBA Libreoffice

Tags: vba, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a function finding the first cell in a column containing a value:

```
recherche = colonneRecherche.createSearchDescriptor    
    with recherche                     
        .SearchString = valeur
        .SearchCaseSensitive = false    
        .SearchByRow = true          
        .SearchWords = false          
    end with
resultat = colonneRecherche.findFirst(recherche)
    if isnull(resultat) then
        RechercherValeur = "NO RESULT!"
        Exit Function
    else
        thisComponent.CurrentController.select(resultat)
        a.nom = "TEST"
        RechercherValeur = a
        Exit Function
    End If
```

The line containing "select" selects the good cell, but I'd like to get the **row number of the cell without selecting it**. I tried

```
resultat.Row
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it by myself:

```
Msgbox "Row: " + resultat.cellAddress.Row
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used LibreOffice and I don't speak French, but if your VBA is like Excel VBA then you may be using an incorrect method.

There is no `FindFirst` in Excel (unlike Access), however there is a `Find` method.

The following VBA returns the row number of the first match:

```
Sub testFind()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("abc")
    If f Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Found on row: " & f.Row
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's the point: Excel macros aren't the same as LibreOffice one's... Your solution is perfect for Microsoft Office, but doesn't work on Libreoffice. Thanks, though :)